# Comparing values in any order

Tags: java, enums, comparison

I though this was a common problem, but i can't find any solution to it.

There's an enum, something like

```
public enum MyEnum { C, G, A, T, U }
```

I need to compare one enum instance with another, like this:

> C complements G
>   G complements C
>   A complements T
>   T complements A
>   U complements T
>   T complements U

How can i do it without writing code like this:

```
public boolean complements(MyEnum other) {
    if(this.compareTo(C) == 0) {
        if(other.compareTo(G) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is "complements" supposed to relate to `compareTo`?

Comment: When i say C complements G, it's a domain-specific talk. In code, i just want to return `true` when i call `C.complements(G);`.

Comment: Shouldn't `U` be one of the enum values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not have a `complements` field? You can have it be an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

```
enum MyEnum {
    G, C, A, T, U;

    static {
        C.complements = EnumSet.of(G);
        G.complements = EnumSet.of(C);
        A.complements = EnumSet.of(T);
        T.complements = EnumSet.of(A, U);
        U.complements = EnumSet.of(T);
    }

    private EnumSet<MyEnum> complements;

    public boolean complements(MyEnum other) {
        return complements.contains(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, except `T` complements both `A` and `U`.

Comment: But you have two member `T`s.

Comment: @ssedano `asList()` is an O(1) operation, the only overhead is instantiating a new object, which isn't much. In any case, yes, both variants are still possible.

Comment: @ssedano See the edit, I decided to use an `EnumSet` instead.

Comment: How are EnumSets stored? Is it an array (with linear search time) or a tree, hashset?

Comment: @CommuSoft As bit vectors. They're faster than other set implementations when used with enums.

Comment: Unless the number of options is of course extremely large and the amount of redundancy becomes quite high. Although I agree it's a very efficient option.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the easiest solution in this case would be:

```
public boolean complements(MyEnum other) {
    switch (this) {
        case C:
            return other == G;
        case G:
            return other == C;
        case A:
        case U:
            return other == T;
        case T:
            return other == A || other == U;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this pattern would introduce high coupling, a bad smell in design patterns... But I like the rainbow dash icon :P

Comment: The `case A:` is incomplete. However +1 because it's a simple and nice solution. @CommuSoft it looks like DNA and RNA complements so that will no change for a while, I guess :P

Comment: @dic19 exactly haha. it really won't change, i guess i will just take this solution instead. but isn't there a cleaner one if i find myself in the same situation with values not set in stone?

Comment: Yeah I made the connection with DNA (RNA uses Uracyl so `U`). But in general it's not an elegant way to solve this... But it works, no doubts about that. Case `A` is not incomplete: it will move to the next label.

Comment: @wingleader - For a general solution, you should probably go with a library that implements set theory relations. A couple of free ones are [here](https://github.com/pconrad/AwesomePrelims/tree/master/java/relations) and [here](http://www.brothersoft.com/set-theory-relations-in-java-487067.html) (I haven't used wither one, so can't attest to their quality. At least the sources could give you ideas for your own general pairing class if neither does the trick.)

Comment: Agreed, in general it's not a good practice. I still thinking `case A` is incomplete because it should return `other == T`. Otherwise switch will continue until reach `default` option and then it will return `false`.

Comment: Well the complement of `A` is `T`. `U` is in fact chemically spoken almost equal to `A`.

Comment: @dic19 - In the case of `A`, you want exactly `other == T`. (How else would you you complete the `A` case?)

Comment: Sorry, I used *would* instead *should* and maybe I was misundesrtood. Of course A will be completed only by T. My point is `case A:` should be `case A: return other == T;` Doesn't it?

Comment: @dic19 This is equivalent, try it. ;)

Comment: @dic19: not at all, personally I dislike such shortcuts most of the time. Especially since they are language specific. `C#` for instance doesn't allow such syntax. When you use 10 languages on a daily basis, such structures can become quite complicated...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static data structure (e.g. a Map) to store the pairings.
Then you can look-up the values in the Map from your complements() method.

Here is the code:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    C, G, A, T, U;

    private static final Map<MyEnum, EnumSet<MyEnum>> complementsMap;

    static {
        complementsMap = new EnumMap<MyEnum, EnumSet<MyEnum>>(MyEnum.class);
        // complements pairings
        complementsMap.put(C, EnumSet.of(G));
        complementsMap.put(G, EnumSet.of(C));
        complementsMap.put(A, EnumSet.of(T));
        complementsMap.put(T, EnumSet.of(A, U));
        complementsMap.put(U, EnumSet.of(T));
        complementsMap.put(T, EnumSet.of(U));
    }

    public boolean complements(final MyEnum other) {
        return complementsMap.get(this).contains(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum items can hold fields:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    C("G"),
    G("C"),
    A("T"),
    T("AU"),
    U("T");

    private String complement;

    private MyEnum (String complement) {
         this.complement = complement;
    }

    public boolean complement(MyEnum blah) {
        return complement.contains(blah.name());
    }
}
```

You can use this like `MyEnum.G.isComplement(MyEnum.C)` which return true.

Comment: Solved, using strings... Although I agree it's not that efficient, its a work around with low coupling...

Comment: I like the direction you are going so will correct your problems but next time try to compile your code before you post it.

Comment: Well I didn't know `U` was part of it initially... But one should indeed read the questions more carefully. Using strings instead of an array of basically chars is indeed an efficiency improvement.

Comment: No `C` will return false when given as a complement to `C`. Because it well search if `C` is a character in the string `"G"` which is false. Now it works correct...

Comment: @GyroGearless http://ideone.com/NLJeSg C.complement(c) returns false, i didn't get what you meant.

Comment: Comment referred to a previous version, deleted!